# Jmeter Regular Expression issue with excluding patterns

Tags: regex, jmeter

I need a regex to find the last match of a pattern in JMETER
This is the string I have

> "blah blah n="12" blah blah n="13" blah blah n="14" KEYWORD blah blah"

what I want is the last n=value before the keyword

This is the regex I tried,

```
n="(.(?!n=).)"KEYWORD
```

but the regex matches everything between first n= and KEYWORD. It doesn't exclude the n= patterns in between

Can somebody help me crack this nut??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why do you need the negative lookahead, when there is the KEYWORD following? Then you could just use

```
n="(\d+)"\s*KEYWORD
```

and find your value in "$1". See it [here on Regexer](http://regexr.com?32t2k).

If the KEYWORD can change you can ensure with a negative lookahead that there is no more "n=" following in the row

```
n="(\d+)(?!.*n=)
```

[See it on Regexr](http://regexr.com?32t2n)

and if you don't want the "n="" to be part of the match, you put that in a look behind assertion:

```
(?<=n=")\d+(?!.*n=)
```

[See it on Regexr](http://regexr.com?32t2q)

Comment: Thanks for the help. The second one worked for my case. The first one didn't as there can be some strings before the KEYWORD and between n="value". Sorry for not mentioning it correctly in the question.